# Detect account balance changes in a transaction

Tags: transactions

I'm trying to analyze transactions, but I can't get answers to some questions.

1. In this transaction: `37YEqu9NVmAd6wiV9HaQkoQgrPJzooxC1Hhwors43daJbAQHbHzcoqxJF8PL94YKt8CUaBMu71UW8pjjVRrXiEFS`
   length of meta.postBalances is 42, and the length of transaction.message.accountKeys is 13. How do I know which account balances meta.postBalances[13:41] represents if there are no corresponding accounts in transaction.message.accountKeys?
2. What does it mean when the length of meta.preTokenBalances is not equal to the length of meta.postTokenBalances? e.g `33Xh1SnWZ6gJVUsPG6xXfis9FjamEgaYWYzBo3xSenyb5kpJbDGkfpG6LMBtUpLMaaEn37FSptKZsEpiK28PiCTo`

Answer (score 2):

1. This transaction uses address-lookup-tables, which are special accounts that store addresses. Transactions may reference addresses stored inside of the address-lookup-table during construction, reducing the size of the transaction. You can find more information about these at https://docs.solana.com/developing/lookup-tables. To answer your question, you'll also need to look in the `loadedAddresses` array when loading the transaction.
2. It looks like account `5y9RGK1bmQXZ3hv6v8ygU7GcFGam2NDmdtb8KUrgPo5y` was created during this transaction, so it had no balance to start, and ended with some balance. I'm not 100% sure on this, but it's the only difference that I can see.